# Solving recurrence relation $a_{n+1} = \frac{3a_n^2}{a_{n-1}}$

Tags: reference-request, recurrence-relations

I am currently studying recurrence relations and I am stuck at a particular problem:

$$a_{n+1} = \frac{3a_n^2}{a_{n-1}}$$ for $n \geq 1$, starting with $a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = 2$.

In the lecture, we only covered linear recurrence relations, so I am kind of lacking of an ansatz. My idea was making a clever "coordinate" transformation so that the above relation will be simplified. I thought about using something like $\exp$ or $\log$ in order to be able to use addition theorems so that the expression becomes a normal recurrence relation (the square becomes a "$2\times$" and the division a $-$). I am worried about that, because I am only dealing with discrete values.

Therefore, can someone give me a good recommendation for an overview how to deal with this and how I can find a suiting ansatz?

Comment: Hint: consider $\log a_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggested, applying $\log$ on both sides we obtain

$$\log a_{n+1}=2\log a_n-\log a_{n-1}+\log 3.$$

Answer (score 1):

A way to solve this is to write:

$$
\frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n} = 3 \frac{a_n}{a_{n - 1}}
$$

or, equivalently:

$$
\frac{a_{n + 2}}{a_{n + 1}} = 3 \frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n}
$$

This suggests the change of variables:

$$
u_n = \frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n}
$$

So $u_{n + 1} = 3 u_n$, and so $u_n = 3^n u_0$. I.e.:

$$
\frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n} = 3^n \frac{a_1}{a_0}
$$

This in turn gives:

$\begin{align*}
  a_n 
     &= \prod_{1 \le k \le n - 1} 3^k u_0 \\
     &= 3^{n (n - 1) / 2} \cdot u_0^{n - 1}
\end{align*}$